# Why would my health insurance provider call me to spontaneously offer a lower rate?

Tags: health-insurance, switzerland

Asking anonymously for privacy.

I have had both basic and extended health insurance at company "A", which is now a sub-brand of company "B".

Today, I was called by someone identifying as from company B. They started by thanking me for my fidelity, since I've been with them for my entire life, and then asking me if I wanted to switch my basic coverage from company A to company B, to save a small amount of money. According to them, there would be "no difference" for me, only slightly lower fees.

Why would they do this?

I think their claim sounds believable, since this is the law-mandated basic coverage. On the other hand, I fail to see what's in it for them. It wouldn't be even to simplify things administratively, as it's probably simpler for them to handle both the basic and extended coverage under the same brand.

I'm very wary of touching my health insurance, because I have several lifelong conditions requiring an expensive treatment; the treatment cost alone (covered by the basic, law-mandated plan) barely lets them break even on my fees, before any other medical expenses come into account.

Is this a backhanded trick that will somehow help them make my case more profitable for them? Or are they just afraid I'll switch to a less expensive provider for the basic coverage?

Comment: Is the coverage identical for the policies at both companies?  Is there a secondary source that can verify this?  For example, if this is Medicare, there are lots of resources available.

Comment: @BobBaerker it's in Switzerland; basic coverage is provided by private companies, but is mandatory for residents, insurance companies cannot refuse to insure you, and the conditions and price models are set by the cantonal authorities. There is a little variation between companies but it's generally at most 10%. Then you have a free choice of complimentary insurance with various rates and coverages, that you can get from the same or a different company, but here they were only talking about the basic coverage.

Comment: My bad, I missed the Switzerland tag.  Ask your company to provide a side by side comparison of the two policies and where there are differences, determine if any changes adversely affect you and to what degree.  If they are minor or non existent then the premium savings might be worth it.  IMHO, insurance companies do not offer you premium savings out of the goodness of their heart.  There's usually something in it for them.

Comment: There are legitimate reasons why they might want to make such an offer: goodwill (they think you'll appreciate the offer and stick with them longer); good PR (word gets out that they're doing this & they get more customers); business reorganization (maybe they're planning on phasing out company A & want to move customers to B because they can run the business more cheaply).

Comment: You say "someone identifying as from company B." Are you in doubt about this? If so, you should call them to verify the offer.

Comment: @Kryten I thought about the latter, and I asked them about it. They explicitely said that it would not make things simpler for them, as I would then be getting basic coverage from company A and extended coverage from company B.

Comment: @Not_Einstein I generally try to keep in mind that anyone calling me isn't necessarily who they claim to be. But in this case they didn't ask for any personal information. I'll do that, but I just wanted to make sure I didn't miss something obvious before calling them.

Comment: The only reason I can think is to make company A look more profitable by taking out loss making portfolio and sell company A for large valuation. Loyalty doesn't make sense as they can do this via Company A as well. If company B historically offered lower rates, then another reason could be some company acquisition law giving same rates to acquired customers.

Comment: Is this an "act now or you will lose this great offer" situation?? if not, I would just sit and watch and listen for a while. Companies that are already collecting money from you usually don't act unless there is something in it for them. If you additionally hear about them taking extra steps to save you money in a TV commercial or mail correspondence, well then that's another thing... Otherwise, I'd wait it out until the real reason becomes more obvious. I'd also be worried about some longtime guaranteed "small-print" benefits you could be potentially losing or something of that nature.

Comment: On a less skeptical side... I don't know what "sub-brand" means or exactly entails, but if it allows direct competition between A and B... Then that could be no different from one cable-tv provider calling asking you to switch. (I'd still be concerned about what I might lose)... Perhaps B has plans on not being a "sub-brand" of A in the near future and is stealing as much base as possible... You're already in their system, they'd know exactly what to offer you.

Answer (score 1):

Is the health insurance market competitive where you are, i.e., are there several insurers with rates at or below what you're paying? Especially if it's become more competitive and rates for new customers have ticked down, they may be proactively seeking to retain their customers.

It is similar to a bank spontaneously [offering to refinance](https://money.stackexchange.com/q/118731/64920) your mortgage at a lower rate, rather than have you refinance with a competitor. Another analogy would be a landlord proactively lowering your rent a bit if the rental market has softened, so you're not as tempted to move to another place offering incentives.